# Django filter - filter a property of a model through a range of values

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have this model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_birth = models.DateField()
```

and this property to calculate years and months of birth

```
    @property
    def eta_annimesi(self):
        date2 = datetime.combine(self.date_birth , datetime.min.time())
        now  = datetime.now()                        
        duration = (now.year - date2.year) * 12 + now.month - date2.month
        years = duration // 12
        months = duration % 12
        if years > 0:
            if months > 0:
                msg_anni = years.__str__() + ' anni ' +months.__str__() +' mesi'
            else:
                msg_anni = years.__str__() + ' anni'
        else:
            if months > 0:
                msg_anni = months.__str__() +' mesi'
            else:
                msg_anni = 'Appena nato'
        return msg_anni
```

I need to create filters on an html page that allow me to create a range between two integer values. (e.g. from 0 to 2 years)
If it were possible even months but it's not important.

I managed it by giving the possibility to enter the range of two dates but that's not what I need.

Ideas and suggestions?
Thanks in advance to anyone who wants to give me a hand.